# Restrict SSH access by machine

Tags: authentication, ssh, rsa, restrict

I'm trying to set up a server that will be logged into by people paying for a service I offer, but I want to make sure that only those people who I want can access it.  I obviously can't simply give each one a different user account because they could simply share credentials with other people.  Is it possible to restrict SSH access by MAC address or RSA Key or something like that?  By IP doesn't work either because multiple people can sit behind a single router.

Comment: You can always spoof MAC addresses, switch IP addresses, and find a way around your prevention measures. Why not just perform IP filtering and allow only 5 unique machines (in case the IP address changes) to access that account?

Comment: It's a model that might be used in schools so that it's very possible that many people will legitimately use the same IP address, so IP is definitely out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use a RSA key, using RSA's PAM modules. http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1177

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no real effective way to tell programmatically who's sitting at the keyboard (which is effectively what you're after). Without more details on what the service is, it's hard for me to offer exact suggestions, but one good bet might be to design the service such that it's less useful on a shared account.

Comment: We're tunneling DNS requests through SSH to our server to avoid web blockers.